# problema con switch en php

Tags: php

hola soy nuevo en esto de la programación estoy tratando de hacer por medio de un radio button  las operaciones básicas pero no me funciona la suma ni la resta no entiendo por que

```html
<form method="POST" action="resultado.php">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Numreo 1</th>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="n1"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Numero 2</th>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="n2"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="operacion" value="suma">Suma</input>
        <input type="radio" name="operacion" value="resta">Resta</input>
        <input type="radio" name="operacion" value="producto">Multiplicacion</input>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="operacion" value="division">Division</input>
        <input type="radio" name="operacion" value="potencia">Potencia</input>
        <input type="radio" name="operacion" value="modulo">Modulo</input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="ENVIAR"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
//otra pagina
<?php 
  $n1 = $_POST['n1'];

  $n2 = $_POST['n2'];


  switch ($_POST['operacion']) {
   case 'suma':
     echo "el resultado es ".$n1+$n2;  
    break;
   case 'resta':
     echo "el resultado es ".$n1-$n2;
    break;
   case 'producto':
     echo "el resultado es ".$n1*$n2;
     break;
   case 'division':
     echo "el resultado es ".$n1/$n2;
      break;
   case 'modulo':
     echo "el resultado es ".$n1%$n2; 
      break;
   case 'potencia':
     echo "el resultado es ".pow($n1, $n2);      
      break;        
   default:
    # code...
    break;
  }
   ?>
```

Comment: Hola Jhonatan, ¡bienvenido a Stack Overflow! ¿Puedes especificar un poco más qué es lo que no te funciona y por qué? O sea, ¿qué esperabas y qué obtienes en su lugar?

Comment: La verdad que ambas respuestas son de calidad, pero me gustaría aportar información útil para quien tenga dudas con un switch php: Explicación de [Switch en PHP](https://www.srcodigofuente.es/curso-php/switch-case-break-default) En este artículo se detalla como se utiliza y algunos consejos avanzados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías comprobar, como mínimo, que los valores llegan antes de tratar de operar con ellos. Por ejemplo:

```
if ( $n1 != "" && $n2 != "" ) {
  swich ...
```

Luego, mete siempre las operaciones matemáticas entre paréntesis cuando estés concatenando con strings para evitar problemas y hacer el código más claro, o mejor mete el resultado de las operaciones en una nueva variable previamente y luego concatena ésta. Por ejemplo:

```
switch ($_POST['operacion']) {
    case 'suma':
        $res = $n1 + $n2;
        echo "el resultado es " . $res;      
        break;
    case 'resta':
        $res = $n1 - $n2;
        echo "el resultado es " . $res;  
        break;
```

Cuando te surjan problemas simplifica y haz trazas / debug.

Answer (score 3):

El problema está en la [precedencia de operadores](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php): el operador concatenación (`.`) tiene la misma precedencia que los operadores de suma (`+`) y resta (`-`) y por eso no te sale el resultado que esperabas.

**Pon las operaciones entre paréntesis para que no existan esos problemas de precedencia**, y eso solucionará el problema:

```
    switch ($_POST['operacion']) {
        case 'suma':
                echo "el resultado es ".($n1+$n2);      
            break;
        case 'resta':
                echo "el resultado es ".($n1-$n2);
            break;
        case 'producto':
                echo "el resultado es ".($n1*$n2);
                break;
        case 'division':
                echo "el resultado es ".($n1/$n2);
                    break;
        case 'modulo':
                echo "el resultado es ".($n1%$n2);  
                    break;
        case 'potencia':
                echo "el resultado es ".pow($n1, $n2);                      
                    break;                              
        default:
            # code...
            break;
```